# React-Native collapsable content

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve this collapsable content(list of selectable buttons) in react-native, could some please suggest on how do we achieve this?Attached the screenshot

[link to the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcNO8.png)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible will helps you to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Abhishek Please refer the module

```
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible
```

> Example Application

```
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/master/Example/App.js
```